# Linux phantom mounts

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

For the second time in a year, I have encountered phantom mounts.  "Normal" system tools show a CIFS mount does not exist, yet it's still really there. Adding or (mass) deleting files is instantly reflected on the remote server.  Below is the slightly redacted output of a 'df', 'mtab', and then what /proc shows is really going on.  Does anyone know how this happens?

```
root@phoenix:/proc# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               38G   12G   25G  34% /
varrun                1.7G  736K  1.7G   1% /var/run
varlock               1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /var/lock
udev                  1.7G   64K  1.7G   1% /dev
devshm                1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md1              1.4T  1.2T   89G  94% /data

root@phoenix:/proc# cat /etc/mtab
/dev/md0 / ext3 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/sys /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
varrun /var/run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=0755 0 0
varlock /var/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devshm /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/md1 /data ext3 rw 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0

root@phoenix:/proc# cat mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/md0 / ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/md0 /dev/.static/dev ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
//10.200.4.4/K /mnt/FC_shares/K cifs rw,mand,relatime,unc=\\10.200.4.4\K,username=XXXXX,domain=XXXXX,uid=0,gid=0,rsize=16384,wsize=57344 0 0
tmpfs /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
/dev/md1 /data ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /var/run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /var/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen phantom mounts in two occasions:

- When using `mount --no-mtab`
- `/` mounted read-only